# Flutter 2 BottomNavigationBar does not show labels from the second item

Tags: flutter

Hi I am new to Flutter 2 and have a question about BottomNavigationBar. Here is the code I am testing

```
class BottomNavigationComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'AL',
              backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'BL',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_rounded),
              label: 'CL',
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm_sharp),
              label: 'DL',
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
    ]);
  }
}
```

and I get the following screen

[image]

If I remove any one of the BottomNavigationBarItem, then the bar will become the follow. You can see that the background color is no longer set.

[image]

Can anyone please help? Thank you

**UPDATE:**

According to @Ali Mahdiyar's suggestion, I get the following screen. It's getting better and showing label. However, the background color seems like does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

update/////

```
class BottomNavigationComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return BottomNavigationBar(
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,////////////this added

unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,///////you can add this to set the items colors 
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'AL',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'BL',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_rounded),
                  label: 'CL',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm_sharp),
                  label: 'DL',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
        ]);
      }
    }
```

also you can set the colors of icon inside the Bottomnavigationbaritesm

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm_sharp,color:Colors.black),
                  label: 'DL',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
```

Comment: Hi @Ali Mahdiyar, thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and the labels are shown. However, the background color seems like does not work. I tried to set different background color for each item but it's all white now.

Comment: whould you put an image to resolve background color too

Comment: Do you mean instead of using the backgroundColor, I can use an image? hmm....sounds fine but a bit weird

Comment: Oh, sorry I miss understood it. Please see the update section at the end of my post

Comment: you mean the background color of your bottomnavigation bar or items background color?

Comment: I mean items background color. I set different items with different background color but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: When I add a background color for the whole nav bar, it works as expected. but the background color for each item does not work.

Comment: and if the answer was useful sing it as correct answer

Comment: set the color inside the icon

Comment: Yea, I think I misunderstand the backgroundColor of each item. Seems like it has nothing to do with the background color of each item. It is the nav bar's color when the item is selected. I think I am happy with what I have now. Thanks @Ali Mahdiyar